# What are the relative stress order among noun, adj., verb., adv., negative word when they meet in a sentence? Is there grammar sentence stress rules

Tags: stress, intonation

the example sentences are, "the dog ate a piece of black meat quickly. " , "Tom bought an extremally interesting book in the store for his brother." I hope get the default sentence stress rule like "the dog(n., 0.8) ate(verb, 0.4) a piece of black(adj., 0.5) meat(n., 0.6) quickly(ending, 1.0). ", assume 1.0 is the highest pitch.

Is there a popular authentic book to describe American intonation in the long sentences?

Comment: There isn't a sentence pattern. There are intonation contours like y/n questions or commas that help indicate stress, but stress and intonation are interlocked and can't be separate.

Comment: when n., verb., pronoun meet in a same sentence, the n. gets the strongest stress, then verb...., when n., verb., adj., adv. in a same sentence, I want to know how is going.

Comment: It doesn't depend on part of speech; it depends on how the speaker wants to be understood and it's not a matter of counting levels -- you can do that on one sentence by one speaker on one occasion, but that speaker would pronounce it differently the next time, and a different speaker would have a different pattern.